Whose perspective on evidence is correct: Hitchens's razor or Carl Sagan's?
Hitchens's razor states, "What can be asserted without evidence can also be dismissed without evidence," while Carl Sagan argues, "Absence of evidence is not evidence of absence." What are your thoughts on this?

Whose perspective is "correct" depends on one's perspective. "What are your thoughts" questions are off-topic here. And one-liners out of context are not particularly cogent, these two can be interpreted to both be correct, for example, see When is absence of evidence not evidence of absence?.

Absence of evidence frequently is evidence of absense (not always though). Especially in cases where you're explicitly looking for evidence that you should expect to find. People misuse this phrase a lot and, speaking in a bayesian sense, it's just often not right.

Hitchen's razor brings up ambiguity and depending upon the context it is being used might fall flat, Carl's on the other hand is a logical observation regardless of the scenario. Also  personally, I think Carl Sagan was more of a scientific and philosophical intellectual than Hitchens was, Hitchens was the face of media more focused with politics and journalism.

Does this answer your question? When is absence of evidence not evidence of absence?

(See Quote Investigator for the origins of Sagan's quote.)

The title suggest that you view these statements as conflicting. They aren’t.

They are two aphorisms intended to make a point, not to be considered the last word. You will find similar superficial contrasts in lots of everyday maxims, such as 'penny wise, pound foolish' which might be taken as conflicting with 'look after the pennies and the pounds will look after themselves'.
Hitchens' phrase is related to the principle of the burden of proof, pointing out that unsubstantiated claims are just that, and there is no obligation on anyone to prove that they are incorrect. If you feel entitled to claim X without any justification, I should feel entitled to suppose not X with an equal lack of justification.
Sagan's point is different. He is saying that a lack of evidence for X doesn't prove X must be wrong.
Given that, there isn't really a conflict between the two statements, as they are making different points. For there to have been a conflict, Hitchens would have to have said something like 'what can be claimed without evidence can be proved wrong without evidence', which of course would be a ludicrous claim.
